# Can someone provide a readable discourse on factorization, norms, maximality of norms of ideals in a number field.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have already introduced myself as the communications liaison of a small study group of math Ph. D.'s who are thirty plus years away from grad studies. We are currently working on Stewart & Tall's ANT and Fermat's Last Theorem. We are having as rough time with Chapter 5 and are seeking alternative readings. Unfortunately there seem to be as many approaches to ANT as there are textbooks written. This makes it much harder to find those "alternate Readings" which follow their (Stewart & Tall) development.
Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is more of algebraic number theory than of number theory. You could consider retagging it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up some [notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/mathhonss212/notes.html) on Algebraic Number Theory. I was following Stewart & Tall but also a couple of other books. See if you find anything useful there.

Comment: if I haven't thanked you already, let me do it now. If you continue to develop these notes and solutions I would be very, very happy if you would email them to me.

Comment: Dave, I doubt that I'll get back to this until the next time I teach the course, and that might be next year, or it might be never. But if you can find my email address and drop me a line, I'll try to put it somewhere where it will remind me of your request.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my favorites:
[Simple and direct method](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Algebraic_Number_Fields.html?id=RT5R_29X69wC&redir_esc=y) By Janusz
[One of my favorite authors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540653996) by Jürgen Neukirch
[Available online notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) J.S.Milne
[A classic](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Lectures_on_the_Theory_of_Algebraic_Numb.html?id=QEocn1kbfxAC&redir_esc=y) Hecke
[If you know some background in the integration on groups, then this is a classic!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540586555) André Weil
I know not your book, so I cannot say if they follow the approaches in your book, but I am sure that the number of approaches to ANT is not too large, so that they are essentially equivalent.(Per chance they look different at first glance, but they might turn out to be equivalent in the end.)
Hope this helps.